# Unable to catch the "created" notification from FileSystem by FileSystemWatcher when file is created by third-party program C#

Tags: c#, service, filesystemwatcher

**Brief:**

I got stuck with an interesting but strange occurrence. There is a service which is installed on WindowsServer. This server uses `FileSystemWatcher` to get the notifications about created files (*.xlsx) in the directory. When the event is raised it must write the name of file to my `Log.txt` file.

**Issue:**

When a file is created by some program no event is raised. But when I do that copying operation manually, i.e. using `TotalCommander`, I get the log as it should be.

**Findings:**

- Firstly, the directory has the appropriate permissions for this
  service otherwise it wouldn't launch. The folder isn't shared over
  the network.
- Secondly, the buffer can't be overflowed (there is only one file
  generated per minute). So watcher can't miss it. Moreover handler is
  short enough to keep up with this requirement.

I've looked through lots of topics but nothing worked.

Perhaps there is some difference between the respective operations (manually and automatically)? Maybe the program blocks the file, I'm not certain about that.

Comment: The file may be created initially with a `tmp` extension, and then renamed. Try handling also the [`Renamed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed) event.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I've just done it. You're right. Thank you.